# My Dell XPS desktop gave a BSOD this morning

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, bluetooth

My Dell XPS Desktop gave a blue screen of death this morning. Its a XPS 8700 model. I think the issue might be the Bluetooth driver, which I was trying to use at the time. (I've since turned it off.) When I got this desktop it was a Windows 8/8.1 machine, which I've upgraded to Windows 10 Pro, so the drivers may be out of date for that OS. I've gone to Dell's website to try and figure out what driver I should use for the Bluetooth device. The website discusses something called Dell Update Application. Is that what I need in order to have it review my system and see what drivers I should use?

Comment: Whats the error message saying at the bottom of the BSOD? This might be able to help you pinpoint the error and find a solution

Comment: It says the Stop action was caused by a Driver Power State Failure.

Comment: You can use the Dell Update or download the drivers [here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/xps-8700/drivers/advanced).

Comment: Thanks, spike_66. Looks like I've already got the latest driver.

Comment: [analyze the dumps with windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) to see what happens. if you need help, share the dmp files via Onedrive share link

Comment: Drivers are under "Modem/Communications" on this page....http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/xps-8700/drivers?os=wt64a